# SSD got only 500 Mb reserved for the system and don´t let me Delete this partition nor alocate the 450 Gb of free memory that are not alocated

Tags: ssd

I bought a new SSD to use in my old computer and so once a plugged it and started the process of allocation it only allocated 500 Mb that are said to be reserved to the System, letting the 450 Gb that rested not allocated. Also the disk won´t let me delete this partition nor allocate the empty space, even though I can click to do it.

Disk 1 is the new one

[image]

So, after that I tried Delete this partition to retry the process.

Delete partition action

[image]

And strangely it did not deleted any thing, since the field is still there, and once I plugged it again, even the name returned.

Because of this I jumped to try to at least allocate the rest of the memory like showed in then next image. Notice that in this image you can also see the deleted partition that doesn´t go away.

Allocate partition action

[image]

And so I waited for like 15 minutes for just so it show an screen saying that:

> Failed to complete the operation because the Disk Management console display is not up to date. Update the display using the update task. If the problem persists, close the Disk Management console and restart Disk Management or restart your computer.

And so I did only to return to the same situation.

This is the image of the message that appeared.

[image]

Comment: Why so much fuss about 0.1% of disk space ?

Comment: @Luuk I agree about the fuss with the system reserved partition but not being able to create a partition in the remaining unallocated space?

Comment: @Artur How is the new SSD recognized in UEFI ("BIOS")? Does it have any "RAID", Intel RST or similar setting? Which Windows version?  Please [edit] the question accordingly.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Sorry, i must have overlooked that because of all the foreign (Portuguese?) language stuff.   But indeed adding a new partition/volume should be possible,

Comment: This raises a question: are you sure the disk is new? You may look at the SMART report to have some information about this (power on time, etc...) (CrystalDisk Info will show the SMART report, but many others utilities will do)

Comment: 500MB is the default size for that particular partition.  Are you positive that is the correct English translation?  Because I have seen that message before, and I get zero Google results, except this question which indicates you have a translation error.